# Forward Dependency for Win32 functions

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to make my visual C++ project compatible with all windows server versions. One of the functions I am using `PssCaptureSnapshot` is only supported on server 2012 R2, that is fine since it is not required to run, I added version checking functionality so it would only run on compatible versions.
The problem is my program still crashes when running on older versions if `PssCaptureSnapshot` is referenced in the code even if its not called. The only solution I can think of is to create a separate embedded dll resource and dynamically load `PssCaptureSnapshot` if the windows version is compatible.
Is there any other way I can add some sort of forward compatibility so that I can run my binary on older windows versions even if `PssCaptureSnapshot` referenced but not called?

Comment: Use [GetProcAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) instead of referencing directly, see the example on the linked page.

Comment: Another technique is [delay-load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of scenario that delay loading was invented for.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'm curious how delayed loading would work because `PssCaptureSnapshot` is part of kernel32.dll which I need other functions from. Is it possible to delay load a single function?

Comment: I ended up using @dxiv suggestion instead of creating a separate dll, Thanks!

Comment: @rooter Glad it helped. You can't use delay loading for kernel32 APIs, see [Why can't I use the linker to delay-load a function from kernel32?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100201-00/?p=15123).